# Readonly Replica of Elasticsearch Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I need a replication of my elasticsearch cluster data over one node, in order to run query in dev environment over real data. Is there any way I could replicate all of my elasticsearch cluster data to one node that is accessible in dev env?

Comment: Hi. I believe this would usually be done by restoring a snapshot into an existing cluster, or using the `reindex` API in order to pull an index from a remote cluster and push it into a local/dev one.

Comment: how often do you want to update dev clusters data?

Comment: at least every 1 hour

Comment: for start, you could easily copy data from Elasticsearch data path to a new server on the new cluster . but for the update, I think you should schedule the Reindex, base on one hour.  you can reindex with rest api, logstash, elastic java client and ... .